# Group rows in equal sized blocks and get aggregate of some columns

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

Suppose I have a table with columns `name` and `age` with following data:

```
name  | age
------|-----
harry | 12
adam  | 13
eve   | 14
jill  | 14
John  | 16
alice | 19
smith | 33
bill  | 43
bob   | 66
jones | 78
```

I want to first arrange the rows in increasing order of age (already done above)
Then I want to supply a "group size", say 3. So mentally divide the table in blocks of 3 rows starting from top

```
name  | age
------|-----
harry | 12
adam  | 13
eve   | 14
------------
jill  | 14
John  | 16
alice | 19
------------
smith | 33
bill  | 43
bob   | 66
------------
jones | 78
```

Last block can be less than 3 if num rows is not a multiple of 3. 
I need the top and bottom values of the age column in each block. So the output should be:

```
min age|max age
-------|-------
  12   | 14
  14   | 19
  33   | 66
  78   | 78
```

The naive way using nested tables is not efficient:

```
select 
  min(T.age), 
  max(T.age) 
from 
  (select 
     age 
   from 
     users 
   order by age limit 3 offset 6
  ) as T
```

I prefer to avoid selecting rows and work only with aggregates.

Database: MySQL and H2.

Comment: Do you want MYSQL to do all this or are you considering doing this in code?

Comment: Want to do this via SQL code itself.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.:

```
SELECT MIN(age)
     , MAX(age) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , FLOOR(@i:=@i+1/3)*3 i 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY age,name) n 
        GROUP 
           BY i;
```

Comment: In case anyone's thinking of upvoting this, this isn't how I would solve this problem nowadays